# {% static %} ignores ManifestFilesMixin

Tags: python, django

I have a class like this:

```
class StaticStorage(ManifestFilesMixin, S3BotoStorage):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['custom_domain'] = settings.CUSTOM_STATIC_URL
        kwargs['location'] = 'static'
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

I use this as the storage for my static assets:

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 's3utils.StaticStorage'
```

the "collectstatic" commands runs just fine:

```
Post-processed 'admin/js/actions.js' as 'admin/js/actions.42b74ac13f07.js'
Post-processed 'admin/js/LICENSE-JQUERY.txt' as 'admin/js/LICENSE-JQUERY.3c20255                                                    38601.txt'
Post-processed 'admin/js/timeparse.js' as 'admin/js/timeparse.a298a7ede5c3.js'
Post-processed 'admin/js/jquery.min.js' as 'admin/js/jquery.min.397754ba49e9.js'
Post-processed 'admin/js/inlines.js' as 'admin/js/inlines.ec5c4bfbf84d.js'
Post-processed 'admin/js/calendar.js' as 'admin/js/calendar.df720acbe7bb.js'
Post-processed 'admin/js/jquery.js' as 'admin/js/jquery.08c235d35775.js'
Post-processed 'admin/js/SelectFilter2.js' as 'admin/js/SelectFilter2.2f2bc9e096       
...
```

Still, the "unversioned" static file seems to be served by my application:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://d2rm5zmjfzcov2.cloudfront.net/static/admin/css/base.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://d2rm5zmjfzcov2.cloudfront.net/static/admin/css/dashboard.css" />
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

This might have been caused by using the wrong templates tags to load static files in your templates.
Make sure that you are using {% load static from staticfiles %} and not {% load static %}.

Take a look at the documentation here, in the note :

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-static

You can find this information here too :

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#static

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10282809)

Comment: The first part of my comment gives the answer (use of {% load static from staticfiles %} instead of {% load static %} in template files), the links are used as references.